# How do you know that the user is not active in the session time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I need to release data from the database employed by the user if it is not active in session 1 hour.

how to do?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to store temporary data in Cache? Then you don't have to worry about cleaning it up

Comment: no, this information locks in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the session timeout to one hour in your web.config and place your code in `Session_End` in `Global.asax.cs`